# CSS selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I write the below CSS selector in jQuery. My intention is to get this particular style to work in older IE browsers

CSS:

```
.classA .classB>.classC .classD {
   background-color: red;
}
```

The following jQuery code does not seem to be working

```
$('.classA .classB>.classC .classD').css('background-color':'red');
```

Here is sample html and jquery code to illustare what I am asking for http://jsfiddle.net/58T7C/

Comment: it's working fine [__FIDDLE__](http://jsfiddle.net/58T7C/5/).. some syntax error in ur code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a valid css statement for old IE versions(>= IE7) also.

[Child Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) is [supported from IE 7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors#Browser_compatibility), [Class Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) is supported even in IE6, so if you don't want to support IE6 then you can go with css itself no need for jQuery

but the jQuery version has a syntax error

```
$('.classA .classB > .classC .classD').css('background-color', 'red');
                                                             ^ `,` here
```

Comment: Note that the error is probably due to the OP's confusion about the `object` argument syntax that `.css()` also accepts.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Use a ',' instead of ':' inside the .css call

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. You could put braces to create an object:

```
$('.classA .classB>.classC .classD').css({'background-color':'red'});
```

EDIT:

As @m59 points out, the `.css()` function can be called two ways. One way is with an object. That way allows multiple properties to be set at once. The other way is with two strings, like this:

```
$('.classA .classB>.classC .classD').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Or just use a comma as in the other answers. `.css()` accepts either.